# How can I install multiple versions of Firefox (4.0 and 3.6), preferably using apt

Tags: package-management, firefox, apt

I have the `firefox` package (Firefox 3.6) installed in Ubuntu 10.04. I'd like to install Firefox 4.0 from the Mozilla PPA but keep 3.6? The instructions look like they'll replace the current firefox package with the new firefox. Is it possible to install both using apt-get? Is there a way to name the executables `firefox-3.6` and `firefox-4.0` and have `firefox` point at one of them?

If you can't use apt, what's the best way to install multiple packages with the same name that will automatically update themselves (or at least be easy to update)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use *ubuntu-mozilla-daily* ppa from mozillateam, it won't replace your 3.6. However, you won't get stable versions. For instance, that ppa is distributing Firefox 7.0a1 now.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-trunk
```

If you want Firefox 5 Beta, use **ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next**.

For more info see http://www.webgapps.org/tutorials/firefox/general/installing-other-versions and the [Firefox 4 Mega Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1712247).

If you want to test multiple versions, then check my FoxTester extension:

http://www.webgapps.org/add-ons/foxtester

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxtester/

Comment: Great tip, +1! Question: is mozillateam an official PPA? Will it be maintaned/updated for each upstream release?

Comment: The mozillateam ppas are "semi-official". They are the guys responsible for Firefox on Ubuntu and thy keep their ppa updated. If you want to upgrade Firefox 3.6, then you can use firefox-stable ppa.

Comment: So it installs in /usr/lib/firefox-4.0 tree? And it uses a /usr/bin/firefox-4.0 launcher?

Comment: Yes, it's a completely separate installation. It also clone your profile to ~/.mozilla/firefox-4.0

Comment: Semi-official is good enough for me. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Go for it. The mozillateam ppa is the way to go.

Comment: @lovinglinux: side-question: will Ubuntus repositoies be ever updated to include FF4, just like there is FF3.6 now? So i can apt-upgrade without the need to add (yet another) ppa?

Comment: Possible, when firefox 3.6 is no longer supported by Mozilla. However, Mozilla new development schedule is very aggressive. Firefox 5 beta is already available via firefox-next. Firefox 6 and Firefox 7 are already being developed. So by the time Mozilla stops supporting Firefox 3.6, Firefox 4 will be obsolete.

Comment: The firefox-next ppa is no longer installing side-by-side, but is upgrading the default version.

Comment: But, isnt it an Ubuntu/Cannonical decision to add FF4 to official repos? How's that related to Mozilla's schedule?

Comment: I had to split my reply, because it was too long: Ubuntu has an update policy that only includes security patches. So when some application developer releases a new major version, which usually includes new features and possibly GUI changes, it only gets into the official repos when Canonical releases a new Ubuntu version, which happens every 6 months.

Comment: With the release of Firefox 3.6 Canonical opened an exception, because Mozilla stopped providing security updates for the 3.0 series, which was the default on some Ubuntu versions. So Canonical decided to push Firefox 3.6 into all Ubuntu repos, even those using Firefox 3.5. It wasn't an easy transition and the upgrade caused several problems, specially on those Ubuntu versions that were still using Firefox 3.0.

Comment: So, is not common and not very likely that Canonical will push another major version of Firefox into the official repos, unless Mozilla stops providing updates for the versions currently being used (3.6). Since the development schedule of Firefox now predicts a new major release every 6-12 weeks, is more likely that Mozilla won't support Firefox 3.6 for as long as it supported Firefox 3.0. When that happens, then you might see the latest Firefox being pushed to the official repos, but it probably won't be Firefox 4.

Comment: @MestreLion - I just read an article that says Mozilla won't be providing security updates to older versions, since Firefox will be performing silent upgrades in Windows. This will definitely affect Ubuntu and we might see new versions pushed into the repositories, besides the Ubuntu upgrade policy.

Comment: +1 for each one of your comments... VERY informative. I always wondered how this upgrade policy thing works involving Canonical, upstream, etc. And, for this case in particular, looks like for Maverick and below users, adding the PPA from firefox is really the way to go. Ill add the firefox-stable one, which replaces 3.6 with 4.0 (use same package name). Thanks!

Comment: The firefox-stable repository is the recommended.

Comment: This answer is now out of date and needs to be updated.